# How to update data fields on the server-side?

Tags: node.js, knex.js, strapi, bookshelf.js

### How I write a script and update a collection field from my server?

**I need to update a field of 100 users.**
I was wondering if I can change them from the server, instead of sending update mutations over and over?

[The Queries part of Strapi Documents](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/concepts/queries.html#queries) says:

> You can just call strapi.query('modelName', 'pluginName') to access
> the query API for any model.

#### But it's not clear where to run it?

Do I need to create a plugin?  or Can I create an `updateUserData.js` file and run `node updateUserData.js`?

```js
strapi.query('user').update(  { id: 1 },...
```